# (my)SQL: Select 20 latest entries in logfile from unique persons

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a logfile which logs the insert/delete/updates from all kinds of tables.
I would like to get an overview of for example the last 20 people which records where updated, ordered by the last update datetime DESC

What I have now is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT logfile.idvalue, DATE_FORMAT(logfile.logDateTime,'%d-%m-%Y  %H:%i') AS thedatetime, CONCAT_WS(' ',people.peopleSurname,people.peopleLastname) AS peopleName
FROM logfile,people
WHERE 0=0
AND logfile.tablename='people'
AND logfile.action='update'
AND logfile.idvalue=people.peopleID
GROUP BY logfile.idvalue
ORDER BY logfile.logDateTime DESC,logfile.idvalue DESC
```

But this results in logDateTimes which don't correspond to the datetime of the latest (Max) "update-entry"
What am i missing?!

thanks
Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    logfile lf
WHERE   tablename = 'people'
        AND action = 'update'
        AND logdatetime = 
        (
        SELECT  MAX(logdatetime)
        FROM    logfile lfi
        WHERE   lfi.idvalue = lf.idvalue
                AND lfi.tablename = lf.tablename
                AND lfi.action = lf.action
        )
ORDER BY
        logdatetime DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Create the following indexes:

```
(tablename, action, idvalue, logdatetime)
(tablename, action, logdatetime)
```

for this to work fast.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might be some use...

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT MAX(logdatetime) AS latest_time,
                 idvalue          AS idvalue
              FROM logfile
              WHERE tablename = 'people' AND
                    action    = 'update'
              GROUP BY idvalue) AS max_times
    ORDER BY latest_time DESC
    LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - first solution worked fine and there are probably more solutions to this question..:-)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

If you are selecting the logDateTime within the same query, you are going to get result for every datetime the person has updated the table, i.e. multiple results per person.

**Solution**

Instead use MAX to select the latest datetime for that user.  You can order by the MAX value also using the alias.

**Tested and working code (no sub-query!)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
l.idvalue, 
CONCAT_WS(' ',p.peopleSurname,p.peopleLastname) AS peopleName,
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(l.logDateTime),'%d-%m-%Y  %H:%i') as thedatetime
FROM 
logfile l INNER JOIN people p ON l.idvalue = p.peopleID
WHERE
l.tablename='people' AND l.action='update'
GROUP BY 
l.idvalue, p.peopleSurname, p.peopleLastname
ORDER BY 
thedatetime DESC, l.idvalue DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

*I've used table a alias for people and logfile to make it a bit easier to read and switched to more common join syntax.*

Comment: thanks for your reply - first solution worked fine and there are probably more solutions to this question..:-)

Comment: if you want better performance, removing the need for the sub-query will make a big difference.